# Declare another template variable inside template in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I am totally new to template programming. So I started with some basic template programming. I Have made a header file BinaryTree.h inside which I am getting some errors. Please see below my code:

```
#ifndef BINARYTREE_H_
#define BINARYTREE_H_

#include <cstdlib>
#include<ctime>


template<typename T>
struct Node
{
    T data;
    Node *lChild;
    Node *rChild;
};

template<class T>
class BinaryTree
{
    private:
        Node<T> *root;

        void addHelper(T value, Node<T> *leaf)
        {

            if(leaf == NULL)
            {
                leaf->data = value;
                leaf->lChild = NULL;
                leaf->rChild = NULL;
            }

            else if(leaf->lChild == NULL)
            {
                leaf->lChild->data = value;
                leaf->lChild->lChild = NULL;
                leaf->lChild->rChild = NULL;
            }
            else if(leaf->rChild == NULL)
            {
                leaf->rChild->data = value;
                leaf->rChild->lChild = NULL;
                leaf->rChild->rChild = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                srand((int)time(0));
                int i = rand() % 2;
                if(i == 0)
                {
                    addHelper(value, leaf->lChild);
                }
                else
                {
                    addHelper(value, leaf->rChild);
                }
            }
        }

        void traverseHelper(Node<T> *leaf)
        {
            if(leaf == NULL)
                return;
            traverseHelper(leaf->lChild);
            traverseHelper(leaf->rChild);
            std :: cout << leaf->data;
        }
    public:
        BinaryTree()
        {
           root = NULL;
        }

        void addNode(T value)
        {
            addHelper(value, root);
        }

        void traverseNode()
        {
            traverseHelper(root);
        }
};



#endif /* BINARYTREE_H_ */
```

Now my main test.cpp looks like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "BinaryTree.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    BinaryTree<int> bt;
    bt.addNode(5);
    bt.addNode(6);
    bt.addNode(15);
    bt.addNode(20);
    bt.traverseNode();
    return 0;
}
```

But when I tried to run the the code , it shows me some error

> 0 [main] Containers 8796 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to Containers.exe.stackdump

Can anyone help me where I am getting the error

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to access an element that has not been created.  That was the error I got.  You never made a new Root node.  I highly recommend looking into any debug options your platform has.  I've hit more than 1 error so far.

Here are some steps to fix.

1st, in your `void addNode(T value)` function, you'll need something like this.

```
void addNode(T value)
{
    if (root == NULL){
        root = new Node<T>();
        root->data = value;
        root->lChild = NULL;
        root->rChild = NULL;
    }
    else{
        addHelper(value, root);
    }
}
```

either that, or in your constructor, make a root node and just let it be empty.

2nd.  In your addhelper function you need to create new children first before assigning them.  see below

```
else if (leaf->lChild == NULL)
    {
        leaf->lChild = new Node<T>();
        leaf->lChild->data = value;
        leaf->lChild->lChild = NULL;
        leaf->lChild->rChild = NULL;
    }
```

you then need to do that for the rest of your cases.

During debugging you can see which pointers are NULL and which ones are not, and you can view your code step by step and see when it breaks.

Hope these tips get you on the right track.  Good job so far, the code was very readable and easy to see what was going on.  You're just getting stuck on Null pointers.